# Multiply a UI text field with number - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Just starting learning swift but stuck when trying to multiply an input with another number and display on a label. I get the error that the number isn't a string and tried to cast but didn't work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var entry: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

        answer.text = entry.text * 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the text into a `Double`, an `Int` etc., then convert the calculation to a string.

```
if let entry = Double(entry.text) {
    answer.text = "\(entry * 2)"
}
```

or

```
if let entry = Int(entry.text) {
    answer.text = "\(entry * 2)"
}
```

Comment: Either want an `if let` or a force unwrap for `(Double(entry.text)!`
Same with the Int type casting.

Comment: @boidkan Thanks, I appended my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the entry will hold a number

```
answer.text = String(Int(entry.text)! * 2)
```

Using optional unwrapping instead

```
if let num = Int(entry.text) {
    answer.text = String(num * 2)
}
```